# Is a MSDN subsciption worthwhile for personal use?

Tags: tools

I code primarily in .net at work, but was wondering if home MSDN subscriptions were available/worthwhile as a tool to stay in touch with the latest technology for Microsoft development?

Comment: You might want to think about just subscribing to the magazine if you are just wanted to keep pace with the state of the art: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/default.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For personal use? Most likely. A MSDN subscription usually pays for itself over time. Aside from getting the latest version of Windows for free, there's plenty of other software/perks available (Free 1 year XNA Creators Club premium subscription).

For development purposes? Unless you want to develop for Windows Mobile/Phone 7, you're better off using express versions of Visual Studio since Windows and Visual Studio Professional are the common reasons why people have MSDN subscriptions

Comment: There's an Express version for Windows Phone 7 now - http://www.microsoft.com/express/Phone/

Answer (score 5):

Probably not, unless you're actively working on long-term projects and/or making money on the side.

For everything else, there's the express versions of most of the software.

Answer (score 2):

By the way, I seem to remember that MSDN subscriptions are personal, i.e. if they got one for you at work you can use it at home as well.

Comment: I seem to remember Microsoft extending their licenses for the Office products in that way but didn't realise they had done it for other products.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the cheapest way would be if you had a work laptop with all the tools on it, and you could use that in your free time.

Unless you are planning to write/sell your own software, spend a lot of time etc, as there will be license issues.